# IE input beeping

Tags: asp.net

I hope someone can help. My asp.net application is exhibiting strange behaviour. Whenever I press the Return/Enter key I get a series of beeps/dings. It sort of goes dindindidindindinggggg !

I have reproduced the issue with a small sample application:

```
<%@ Page Language="Oxygene" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.pas" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This only happens in IE, in firefox and chrome there is no beeping.

Also as a side issue, if I remove one of the textboxes then there is no dinging but I get a post back instead.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<%@ Page Language="Oxygene" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.pas" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return false;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This stops the beeping and stops a post-back when only a single input element.

Answer (score 3):

The enter key has submit behavior for forms. The sound you're hearing is Internet Explorer's way of saying that it could not submit the form, as there is no submit button.

This is nothing .NET specific, but rather an intrinsic part of how IE communicates with the user. A quick test, excuse the sloppy HTML:

A form with no submit button will beep when user tries to submit it:

```
<form><input /><input /></form>
```

Adding a submit button will get you the click sound of a form being submitted instead:

```
<form><input/><input/><input type="submit" /></form>
```

You can get rid of *that* sound by preventing the submit:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"><input/><input/><input type="submit" /></form>
```

Then the only problem is that the button is showing, which, i guess, is not what you want. It turns out that hiding it will make the first sound re-appear, unsurprisingly:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input/><input/>
    <input type="submit" style="display: none;"/>
</form>
```

Here, the button is hidden, and so the browser behaves as in the first scenario where there is no button. But if we hide it in a more elaborate way, so that the browser cannot be sure that it's not showing up, we can get around that problem too:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input/><input/>
    <input type="submit" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0;" value="" />
</form>
```

Now, it should be noted that in this last solution, there'll still actually be a button there, that the user cannot see, but can click anyway (it won't submit, tho). I don't advocate this, but if you're going with this solution, you probably want to set width and height to something really small as well. My ambition was not to come up with the best hack, but simply to create a series of instructive examples that illustrates why the browser behaves the way it does given certain situations.

Comment: OK that makes sense, so can I trap the beeping or maybe add a dummy submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not have a Submit button so it may be informing you that there is no automatic post-back handling.  That would be my first guess.

Comment: OK, yes I have no automatic post-back but that is becuase my real application is all AJAX. Is it possible to trap the beeping?